# Replacing data in tables with constraints

Tags: constraints, truncate, toad

How can I import data into a total of 7 tables which have constraints. I've tried to import new data using the import mode copy: delete all records in destination, repopulate from the source but I get this error:

Could not truncate table. Import aborting. Error code:
ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enable foreign keys

My guess is that I need to work out what sequence I can update the data in all 7 tables then I shouldn't get the error code but not sure how to work out what sequence to do this in?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1)You can replace all keys/constraints, then restore them after data import.

2)You can try to import data starting from dictionaries tables...